# Toggle a div to be closed on load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

The following function toggles a div when clicked on the relative id. Any way to set it up so that when the page loads, the div being toggled starts out closed?

I dont want them to be seen until clicked on.

Best,

Joey

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#architects").click(function() {
             $(".exclusive-architects").toggle();
        });
        $("#international").click(function() {
             $(".exclusive-international").toggle();
        });
        $("#designers").click(function() {
             $(".exclusive-designers").toggle();
        });
        $("#historical").click(function() {
             $(".exclusive-historical").toggle();
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Can you provide your html / css? It sounds like you would just have to modify the starting css

Comment: you would be correct, display : none; did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: @JoeIsaacson AJak is correct it would be better to have them all display:none to start with. That way users with a slow connection do not see them appear when the page loads for 1 second then disappear.

Comment: I feel stupid to argue about browsers with **JS disabled** ...anyway right 'cause of that sometimes CSS `display:none;` is not an option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just hide them on dom ready, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".exclusive-architects, .exclusive-international, 
           .exclusive-designers, .exclusive-historical").hide();

        $("#architects").click(function() {
             $(".exclusive-architects").toggle();
        });
        $("#international").click(function() {
             $(".exclusive-international").toggle();
        });
        $("#designers").click(function() {
             $(".exclusive-designers").toggle();
        });
        $("#historical").click(function() {
             $(".exclusive-historical").toggle();
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should just need to add a `display:none` to your starting CSS

Comment: <div id="hidden" style="display:none">

Answer (score 1):

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/atipum/1/edit)**

if your **HTML** looks like this:

```
<div id="buttons">

    <div>toggle architects</div>
    <div>toggle international</div>
    <div>toggle designers</div>
    <div>toggle historical</div>

</div>

<div class="cont"> architects content </div>
<div class="cont"> international content </div>
<div class="cont"> designers content </div>
<div class="cont"> historical content </div>
```

Than **all you need is**:

```
$('.cont').hide(); // HIDE ALL INITIALLY

$('#buttons div').click(function(){
  $('.cont').eq(  $(this).index()  ).toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){ // DOM ready

    $(".exclusive-architects").hide();
    $(".exclusive-international").hide();
    $(".exclusive-designers").hide();
    $(".exclusive-historical").hide();

});
```

it should work :)